# Selecting a single column with an EntityObject and a column name as parameters

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a database context and an EntityObject referenced in my class. 
With a column name passed as a parameter to a method, I want to achieve this:

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA
```

How do I do that with entity framework/linq?

EDIT:
so the method outline should look something like this:

```
public IQueryable<string> GetAllFromColumn(EntityObject object, string columnName)
{

}
```

Comment: You could paste your model code into the question?

Answer (score 0):

context.TableA.Select(record => record.ColumnA).ToList();

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for your answer but TableA and CoulmnA I want to pass in as parameters...

Comment: Then Reflection and System.Linq.Expression will help with it. You will need to get appropriate ObjectSet of context (or DbSet) taking into account that one ObjectSet could be used for several inherited entities and add Expression.MethodCall with Queryable.Select with lambda pointing to ColumnA. One day of coding and debugging and voila, this line of code will be build dynamically :)